# Math.Round not rounding up correctly to 2 decimal points

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to calculate this:

```
xx = 95
yy = 45

Math.Round(((xx/ 60) * yy) / 2, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

result should be 35.625 which is rounded to 35.63

but the result I am getting is 35.62,

What am I missing? why is it ignoring the third decimal to round up to 35.63?

Comment: Be a little more careful when dealing with `double` (or floating point in general), because it doesn't represent the value exactly, but *approximately*. Suppose your real value of `xx` is `94.9999999999999` and thus when you divide you got `35.62499999999999` - but represented as `35.625` then it will be rounded to `35.62`. This is one possibility.

Comment: What datatypes are `xx` and `yy`?

Comment: xx is int and yy is decimal

Comment: In general you should multiply before dividing to avoid this kind of issue. Try `xx * yy * 60 / 2`

Answer (score 3):

I've just checked your code, and it returns 35.63 in my console app (assuming the type of xx and yy variables is a double). 
I can suggest to pull out the first parameter of the Math.Round expression into separate variable and make sure it's evaluated to 35.625.

Comment: As decimal it returns 35.62.

Comment: Yes for decimal it returns 35.62 and the reason is that the exact result of division is 35.624999999999999999999999999 which is rounded to 35.62 because the third digit is 4 and not 5.

Comment: how did you get the 4999999? I changed the 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero to 9, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero and still getting 35.625

Comment: I added part of the formula as a variable as Peppi suggested var iii = (xx/ 60 * 45);
     
             Math.Round((iii / 2), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); but but still getting 35.62

Comment: @GTITC You missed the Peppi point. It doesn't matter if you assign it to a variable or not, type `var rawResult = ((xx / 60) * yy) / 2;` and take a look at the number.

Comment: ok I got the raw result now, what I am confused about is the reason I am checking this total is because in another page of the app I use the same calculations but using JS like $("#grw2").text("$" + (pr / 60 * g2) / 2);  .... In there I originally had a rounding function as well but removed it to get the raw result and I am getting 35.625 .. so why the difference in raw results? any ideas? I need to make both numbers show the same total

Answer (score 1):

Rounds a decimal value to a specified number of fractional digits.A parameter specifies how to round the value if it is midway between two numbers.[MSDN]
((xx / 60) * yy) / 2 gives you 35.62499999999999 and its normal that you get 35.62, because 35.62499999999999 < 35.625,

Answer (score 0):

Its right and the division is right.
your Math result is 35.6249999999 which is rounded to 35.625 or 35.62. In real math you can't round twice so whether you round to 36.625 or 36.62 (5) won't up (2) since it was originally 4 (35.6249999999).
hope I explained it right for you.